# First steps when CentOS have been hacked

Tags: security, centos, brute-force

My server running centos have been hacked and there is a massive ssh bruteforce attack FROM my server to anothers:

```
netstat -at
tcp        0      0 my.server:35466   gdiving.com:ssh             TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 my.server:55683   transitid-prod.com:ssh      TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 my.server:36485   helixent.com:ssh            TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 my.server:34718   agaacqqcis.c04.gridserv:ssh TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 my.server:38034   fengshui4re.com:ssh         TIME_WAIT
tcp        0      0 my.server:48275   mashery.com:ssh             TIME_WAIT
```

And so on. In my top output I see following:

```
23233 root      15   0   968  556  468 S  1.9  0.0   0:00.95 bash
23426 root      15   0   968  556  468 S  1.9  0.0   0:00.74 bash
23454 root      15   0   968  556  468 S  1.9  0.0   0:00.69 bash
23470 root      15   0   968  556  468 S  1.9  0.0   0:00.66 bash
23480 root      15   0   968  556  468 R  1.9  0.0   0:00.66 bash
23489 root      15   0   968  556  468 S  1.9  0.0   0:00.65 bash
23508 root      15   0   968  556  468 S  1.9  0.0   0:00.67 bash
23531 root      15   0   968  556  468 R  1.9  0.0   0:00.62 bash
23589 root      15   0   968  556  468 R  1.9  0.0   0:00.51 bash
```

I'm totally understand that there is only one way to fix this - reinstall system. But I can't do this right now so I asked for help. How can I stop this bruteforce at least? From what point I should start?

Comment: Did they hack the root account or just a user account? If it's a user account, simply disable the user and then [force log them out](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-logout-user-howto/) using the root account. Assuming everything else has been properly hardened, you may not need a full OS reinstall if they only hacked a non-privileged user account. If they got root access you will definitely need to do a full OS reinstall. However, in the meantime, change your root password, log any current users out of SSH and set up public key authentication.

Comment: You could also disable SSH for all but a single (non-root) account with access to "su" or "sudo" and disable password authentication.

Comment: Thanks, Mike. I'm actually did this immediately after I saw signs of invasion. But for now I see this stuff going on. I'm likely need full OS reinstall ...